# Intermittent nginx timeouts having jetty as upstream server

Tags: nginx, web-server, jetty

We do have a weird production issue of `nginx` timeouts. The timeout says below :

```
"upstream timed out(110: Connection timed out)"
```

Here, the upstream server is `jetty` running on the same host where nginx is also running. Jetty is running on port `8080` where nginx is running on `443`.

Having checked the above error, I verified the logs of jetty logs and nginx logs. Though jetty is returning the response in less than a second, the response sent to nginx is being `delayed` by close to `60 secs`. And nginx is timing is firing the timedout alert after 60 secs with http response code of `504`. This is happening `intermittently`.

Below are the logs of jetty & nginx for a timed out request.

**Jetty log :**

> {"evt":1494519426927,"intelId":"50","intelSeq":112506,"intelVer":"1","time":"2017-05-11T16:17:06.927Z","uiCorrelationIdV1":"SUI-1494519425839-42047","threadName":"qtp754853679-357","wResource":"[http://m.xxx.com/search/facet/women/womens-handbags-9780510203/shoulder/*/N-53f3Z7hk9Z1z0roil*](http://m.xxx.com/search/facet/women/womens-handbags-9780510203/shoulder/_/N-53f3Z7hk9Z1z0roil)","wMethod":"GET","wStatus":200,"wDurationMicros":1087801,"wJlpLocation":"","wFwdFor":"NADA","wHostHdr":"m.xxxx.com","wReferer":"[https://m.xxxx.com/search/facet/women/womens-handbags-9780510203//N-53f3Z7hk9?search-term=Bags&sortBy=priceLow&facet=Handbag%20Style](https://m.xxxx.com/search/facet/women/womens-handbags-9780510203/_/N-53f3Z7hk9?search-term=Bags&sortBy=priceLow&facet=Handbag%20Style)","wHttpVer":"HTTP/1.0","wWsgClientIp":"80.192.191.2","wSrcIP":"127.0.0.1","wUserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0
>   (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304
>   Safari/602.1","intelCropped":false,"intelLength":834}

**Nginx log :**

> 2017-05-11T17:18:09+01:00 intelId="56" intelVer="2" wMethod="GET"
>   wResource="/search/facet/women/womens-handbags-9780510203/across-body/shoulder//N-53f3Z7hk9Z1z0roq4Z1z0roil?search-term=Bags&sortBy=priceLow&facet=Handbag%20Style"
>   wStatus="504" wCacheStatus="MISS" wSrcIP="172.17.233.135" wSize="176"
>   wDurationSeconds="60.001" wHostHdr="m.xxx.com"
>   wReferer="https://m.xxxx.com/search/facet/women/womens-handbags-9780510203/shoulder//N-53f3Z7hk9Z1z0roil?search-term=Bags&sortBy=priceLow&facet=Handbag%20Style"
>   wSSL="on" wSSLver="771" wSSLciph="TLS1.2-ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
>   wWsgClientIp="80.192.191.2" wFwdFor="-" wJlpLocation="-"
>   wProtocol="HTTP/1.1" wUpstreamAddr="127.0.0.1:8080" wPort=443
>   s_vi="[CS]v1|2B4D4CA80501261B-600001064000B11D[CE]"
>   s_ppv="jl%253Asearch%2C14%2C100%2C5789%2C414%2C628%2C414%2C736%2C3%2CP" recognisedUser="true" wUiCorrelationIdV1="-" wUserAgent="Mozilla/5.0
>   (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1"
>   deviceType="mobile"

From the above two logs, we can infer that jetty returned a 200 response at `2017-05-11T16:17:06.927Z`, but it was received by nginx at `2017-05-11T17:18:09+01:00`. This 60 plus secs is causing the timeouts. Its bit weird as both nginx and jetty are hosted on the same host.

If someone could help us in debugging the issue or provide suggestions, it would be great.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: I saw this on our servers during high IO load.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderT, our servers aren't under much stress. So, load isn't the issue.